# Localhost IPv6 access forbidden by rule, client: ::1

Tags: nginx

I can see that my Ubuntu VPS, localhost IPv6 getting permission deny warning for certain directories.

```
2019/10/16 06:53:41 [error] 6544#6544: *5415 access forbidden by rule, client: ::1, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-content/uploads/2013/01/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/tag/how-to"
```

This VPS running Ubuntu 18.04, Nginx 1.17.4, Php7.3 and PageSpeed module. I belive that pagespeed getting this error.

Are there any way to allow internal IP to allow directory access?

Comment: How about change permission to 777 for testing purposes, this kind of error happens for many reasons.